# Failed to execute goal org.eluder.coveralls:coveralls-maven-plugin:4.3.0:report on GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, coveralls

I'm trying to set up GitHub Actions for building a maven project with Coveralls on a public repository. For some reason it keeps failing with this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.eluder.coveralls:coveralls-maven-plugin:4.3.0:report (default-cli) on project e-shop-manager: Build error: Either repository token or service with job id must be defined -> [Help 1]
```

I have looked through the coveralls documentation (both plugin and actions-side) to no avail.

Here is the yaml from Actions:

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: 'adopt'
        java-version: '11'
        cache: 'maven'
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean package jacoco:report coveralls:report
    
    - name: Coveralls
      uses: coverallsapp/github-action@master
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.COVERALLS_TOKEN }}
```

where `COVERALLS_TOKEN` is my secret token, 100% sure it's been added as a repository secret.

Here is my maven project configuration too:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.unipd.mtss</groupId>
  <artifactId>e-shop-manager</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>e-shop-manager</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>checkstyle</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
        <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I couldn't find anything elsewhere other than documentation, since I have pretty much copied configs from docs.

Answer (score 0):

The Coveralls GitHub actions isn't necessary when using coveralls-maven-plugin. The token can be specified on the command line (and it will be masqued in the log):

```
mvn clean package jacoco:report coveralls:report -DrepoToken=${{ secrets.COVERALLS_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 0):

While @[Emmanuel Bourg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525725/emmanuel-bourg) is correct, you *also* have the option of upgrading to the [latest version of the Coveralls Github Action](https://github.com/coverallsapp/github-action/releases). Anything above `v2.0` uses Coveralls' [Universal Coverage Reporter](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter) as its underlying integration, which [natively supports Jacoco](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter#supported-coverage-report-formats) format coverage reports.

But an important note about the **Coveralls Github Action**, which could have been why it wasn't working for you before:

The **Coveralls Github Action** is the *only* [Coveralls integration](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations) that uses a token *other* than the [Coveralls Repo Token](https://docs.coveralls.io/api-jobs-endpoint#authentication-coveralls-repo-token) to identify your repo to the [Coveralls API](https://docs.coveralls.io/api-jobs-endpoint). Therefore, you'll either want to *un-set* `github-token`, or else set it like this:

```
    github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

You can read more details about this in my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114249/coveralls-422-couldnt-find-a-repository-matching-this-job) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559368/getting-422-error-while-trying-to-use-coveralls-with-github-actions).