# Coveralls 422: `Couldn't find a repository matching this job. `

Tags: github, github-actions, coveralls, github-secret

I have just configured [this repo](https://github.com/joaocasarin/express-k8s-sqs/) to use coveralls actions as a coverage badge, created the secret as in the image below:
[image]

And as you can see [in here](https://github.com/joaocasarin/express-k8s-sqs/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L57), I am using the correct secret.

However, everytime I run this job I get the response `Bad response: 422 {"message":"Couldn't find a repository matching this job.","error":true}`

I have no idea what to do. I already checked in the coveralls website and the repo is fine... I noticed that github secrets page updated, and neither Coveralls nor Github documentation updated as well, the Coveralls docs is actually useless, it does not help in nothing regarding github.

Comment: Did you solve this problem by any chance? I have same Issue

Comment: hello @Seonghun yes, all I had to do was to add this line: https://github.com/joaocasarin/express-k8s-sqs/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L60

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that [your fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114249/coveralls-422-couldnt-find-a-repository-matching-this-job/76591706#comment131590689_74114249) was correct because, of all [Coveralls integrations](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations), the [Coveralls Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action) is the only one that uses a token other than the [Coveralls Repo Token](https://docs.coveralls.io/api-jobs-endpoint#authentication-coveralls-repo-token) to identify the repo to the [Coveralls API](https://docs.coveralls.io/api-introduction). Since `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` is available from the [Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action) itself, it is meant to be a faster, more convenient way to configure your integration with Coveralls.

As it may help, some more information on [Coveralls integrations](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations):

1. Coveralls has 30+ community-created [language integrations](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#language-integrations).
2. Coveralls has three [official](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#official-integrations) "[integrations](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#official-integrations)": One integration, the [Universal Coverage Reporter](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter), and two (2) CI Service extensions, which use the [Coverage Reporter](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter) as their underlying integration (since `v2.0` of each): the [Coveralls Github Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action) & the [Coveralls Orb for CircleCI](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/coveralls/coveralls).
3. The [Coverage Reporter](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter) is their future direction for all [official integrations](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#official-integrations) and where they are continuing to add official support for new [coverage report formats](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter#supported-coverage-report-formats) and new [CI services](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter#supported-ci-services).
4. The [Coverage Reporter README](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter/blob/master/README.md) includes fairly simple instructions, with checklists, for developers to add support for [more coverage report formats](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter/blob/master/doc/development.md#add-coverage-format-support) and [additional CI services](https://github.com/coverallsapp/coverage-reporter/blob/master/doc/development.md#support-new-ci-options), for which Coveralls will compensate you with a free month of service.