# Getting 422 error while trying to use Coveralls with GitHub actions

Tags: python, github, automated-tests, github-actions, coveralls

I'm trying to set up **Coveralls** to work with **GitHub Actions** for a Python project, and although I've reviewed the [documentation](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action) multiple times and followed all the instructions to the best of my understanding, I'm still facing the following error:

> Bad Response 422 {“message”: “Couldn’t find a repository matching this
> job”, “error”: true}

Here is a minimal version of my YAML file:

```
name: coveralls
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'
      - name: install requirements
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pytest
          pip install pytest-cov
          pip install -r app/requirements.txt
      - name: run tests
        run: |
          pytest --cov=app
          coverage report -m
          coverage lcov
      - name: upload coveralls
        uses: coverallsapp/github-action@master
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          path-to-lcov: coverage.lcov
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is not clear enough at this point:

> | Name | Requirement | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `github-token` | required | Must be in form `github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`; Coveralls uses this token to verify the posted coverage data on the repo and create a new check based on the results. It is built into Github Actions and **does not need to be manually specified** in your secrets store. [More Info](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/authenticating-with-the-github_token) |

While it suggests that the GitHub token does not require manual specification in your secrets store, it is presented as a recommendation rather than a strict rule. It would be more appropriate to state that "it **must not** be manually specified", since using a custom variable like `GH_TOKEN` instead of the default `GITHUB_TOKEN`  will not function properly.

That being said, you need to replace this line:

```
github-token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
```

with this line:

```
github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestion, @[Andreas Volaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19170534/andreas-violaris). We have updated our documentation on the **Coveralls Github Action** [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action#inputs), which now reads:

| Name | Requirement | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `github-token` | *required* | Default if not specified: `${{ github.token }}`. Can be also specified this way: `github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`; Coveralls uses this token to verify the appropriate repo at Coveralls and send any new status updates based on your coverage results. This variable is built into Github Actions, so **do not add it to your secrets store**. [More Info](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/authenticating-with-the-github_token) |

Just a note on the **Coveralls Github Action**: As an extension of the Github Actions CI service, it is the *only* Coveralls [integration](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations)—*[official](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#official-integrations) or [otherwise](https://docs.coveralls.io/integrations#language-integrations)*—that uses a token other than the **Coveralls Repo Token** to identify your repo at Coveralls. The [Coveralls Repo Token](https://docs.coveralls.io/api-jobs-endpoint#authentication-coveralls-repo-token) is a unique identifier that Coveralls generates for your repo and publishes on your [Repo Page](https://docs.coveralls.io/app-ui#repo-page) and [Repo Settings](https://docs.coveralls.io/app-ui#repo-settings) page.